# WLAN0 not coming up

Tags: opensuse, ifconfig, wlan

if have recently installed OpenSuse 11.1 from a dvd and then, following [this advice](http://de.opensuse.org/SDB:Distribution-Upgrade) , upgraded to 11.2, 11.3, 11.4 and finally 12.1 (no comment on this one, please...).
Now the problem is that my wlan0 is not coming up... i have it configured via yast to not use netmanager and a static ip4 adresse. I have found the file [/etc/sysconfig/network/ifcfg-wlan0](https://gist.github.com/2502315) (link to gist.github). which looks good to me.
If the system is just powered on and i then set

```
ifconfig wlan0 $myip up
route add default gw $mygw
```

for wlan0 and a default route. The interface works.
I really would like to get advice how i can solve this. I have looked to the output of dmesg

```
dmesg | grep wlan0
```

and that told me

```
[   31.065187] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   34.212555] wlan0: authenticate with 00:22:b0:99:a6:63 (try 1)
[   34.215568] wlan0: authenticated
[   34.220333] wlan0: waiting for beacon from 00:22:b0:99:a6:63
[   34.270308] wlan0: beacon received
[   34.274061] wlan0: associate with 00:22:b0:99:a6:63 (try 1)
[   34.277096] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 00:22:b0:99:a6:63 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=2)
[   34.277099] wlan0: associated
[   34.285948] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
```

However i cannot interpret this...

Sincerely

Matthias

Comment: After you run the up command, what does `ipconfig wlan0` show?

Comment: did you say "ipconfig"? Is that a typo? Did you mean ifconfig?

Comment: Yes, that would be a typo.

Comment: I appended to the gist i mentioned: https://gist.github.com/2502315

Comment: That output is showing an up status.

Comment: I pût you on hold Until i am back home and then i show you thé output of thé command from before i configure the interface manually. Which also mâles more sense :)

Comment: @Tim: output appended to gist.github.com/2502315

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding `ONBOOT=yes` to your ifcfg file?  That's what I do in RHEL/Centos land.

Alternately, [this SuSE site](http://www.softpanorama.org/Commercial_linuxes/Suse/network_configuration.shtml) says that `STARTMODE=onboot` might be what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the article. Well worth reading (especially because opensuse.de's search-function does not return anything when asked for "startmode").

Comment: Happy to help!  The google terms I used were "opensuse interface configuration file".